# How to default to empty array if property does not exist - es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following code to get `barNames` from an object `bar`:

```
const {[id]: {'name': fooName} = []} = foo || {};
const {'keywords': {[fooName]: barNames}} = bar || [];
```

- Note: `fooName` exists, but doesn't exist in `keywords` as a property

I want to make `barNames` an empty array if an object `fooName` does not exist in `bar.keywords`. I tried to to use the OR operator but it doesn't seem to work. I don't want to use any more ternary operators like `?, :, &&`, etc.

Any hints would be nice.

Comment: Why not use a ternary? Readability is a feature.

Comment: This ended up working better: `const barNames = bar.keywords[fooName] || []`

Comment: It's not just working better, it's the only way it's working. `bar || ...` could be used only if `bar` were undefined. Btw, it's logical OR, not a pipe.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a default initialiser:

```
const {[id]: {'name': fooName}} = foo || {};
const {'keywords': {[fooName]: barNames = []}} = bar || {};
//                                      ^^^^
```

Comment: Yes! Initializing the `barNames` array to empty is the solution. thanks